# Magento cart stored client side or server side?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

If a visitor adds items to their cart on a Magento site, could they follow a URL (maybe containing a session id?) from another machine an see the contents of their cart? Or is the cart stored in a cookie on the client side and therefore not available from another machine?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

See the new [persistent cart feature](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/persistent-shopping-cart-customer-segmentation-just-getting-better/) in 1.6 CE:

> Magento stores a long-term cookie in each browser (per device) once the customer logs in or creates an account using that browser. The long term cookie allows us to re-create some of the session the user had when they were logged in previously. For example, a users shopping cart is re-created upon subsequent visits to the site. It does not allow the customer or another user to access sensitive information. The user will not be able to complete the checkout process or access account information unless they are officially logged in. Persistent shopping cart is completely configurable by merchants, provides an additional way for the merchant to strengthen customer satisfaction and loyalty and helps increase conversion rates.

Comment: thank you. Just so I am clear - persistent cart is on client side, so no way for a visitor to be, say, emailed, a link to their cart, follow that link from another machine, and see their cart?

Comment: No, they need to create an account to 'go persistent'.